Is there a way to solve this error message?
The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
I tried running npx create-expo@latest Helloworld and gave me an error message.
I was expecting a successful message.

Do you have node.js installed in your computer?
